# Strange behaviour using string templates and new COND syntax

Tags: abap

I have spotted a strange behaviour of new `COND` syntax when used inside a string template. It is about string length defaulting. It looks like the length of the string will be defaulted always to what stands after `THEN` even if the condition is not met.

Check out the following piece of code!

```
REPORT zzz.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA(l_bool) = abap_true.
    DATA(l_v_line) = |{ COND #( WHEN l_bool IS INITIAL THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBBB' ) }|.
    DATA(l_v_line2) = |{ COND #( WHEN l_bool IS INITIAL THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBBB' ) WIDTH = 4 }|.
    DATA(l_v_line3) = |{ COND #( WHEN l_bool IS INITIAL THEN 'AAA ' ELSE 'BBBB' ) }|.
    DATA(l_v_line4) = |{ COND #( WHEN l_bool IS NOT INITIAL THEN 'BBBB' ELSE 'AAA' ) }|.
    WRITE /: l_v_line, l_v_line2, l_v_line3, l_v_line4.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

The output

```
BBB
BBB·
BBBB
BBBB
```

The first two variables `l_v_line` and `l_v_line2` are truncated even if the condition evaluates to false. If I put space after `AAA` in `l_v_line3` then it is OK. Putting `BBBB` after `THEN` for `l_v_line4` solves the problem.

My question is: is this behaviour documented anywhere in SAP documentation? I could not find any clues that would have led me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[from ABAP documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/index.htm?file=abenconditional_expression_cond.htm)

> The # character as a symbol for the operand type.
>
> ...
>
> If the operand type is not fully identifiable, an operand with a
>   statically identifiable type must be specified **after the first
>   THEN**. This type is then used.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that this works as expected: `|{ COND #( WHEN l_bool IS INITIAL THEN \`AAA\` ELSE \`BBBB\` ) }|`. The type seems to be then defaulted to string and not char3. Do you see the difference with `|{ COND #( WHEN l_bool IS INITIAL THEN 'AAA' ELSE 'BBBB' ) }|`? :D

Comment: From my perspective:When you use these quotes - \`AAA\` - the type is identifiable, it's a STRING, and strings have no fixed length. When you use 'AAA' - it can be C(3) or STRING, and for some reason SAP decide that it's C(3)