# Conversion exception while working with constructor expressions

Tags: dynamic, abap

I'm working on a routine which moves the lines of a string table (in this case `fui_elements`) into a structure of unknown type (`fcwa_struct`).

```
DATA(li_temp) = ... "fill assignment table here

LOOP AT fui_elements ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_element>).

    ASSIGN COMPONENT li_temp[ sy-tabix ] OF STRUCTURE fcwa_struct 
        TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_field>).

    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        "somethings wrong with the fui_elements data
    ENDIF.
    <lfs_field> = <lfs_element>.
ENDLOOP.
```

If the table `i_field_customizing` (`STANDARD TABLE OF string`) is not initial, I want to use its values.

Otherwise I want to generate an integer table (so that the loop runs equally often regardless of the table's values). Here `lw_max` is the amount of fields the imported structure has:

```
DATA(li_temp) = COND #( WHEN i_field_customizing[] IS INITIAL
                        THEN VALUE t_integer_tt( FOR X = 1 
                                                 THEN X + 1 
                                                 WHILE X <= lw_max 
                                                 ( X ) )
                        ELSE i_field_customizing ).
```

---

But when I run the report with `i_field_customizing` like that:

```
DATA(i_field_customizing) = VALUE t_string_tt( ( `KUNNR` ) ( `NAME1` ) ).
```

I get this exception on the line where I try to construct `li_temp`:

> CX_SY_CONVERSION_NO_NUMBER (KUNNR cannot be interpreted as a number)

---

My current guess is that `COND` gets its type statically. Does anybody know how I can get around this?

Comment: Try it like this and tell if it works: `COND #( WHEN i_field_customizing[] IS NOT INITIAL
                        THEN i_field_customizing 
                        ELSE VALUE t_integer_tt( FOR X = 1 
                                                 THEN X + 1 
                                                 WHILE X <= lw_max ( X ) ) ).`

Comment: Could you also post the definition of the `t_integer_tt` type?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. But now `li_temp` becomes a CString table. This way the `ASSIGN COMPONENT` statement interprets the numbers as fieldnames so the assignment fails.

Comment: `t_integer_tt` is just  `TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF i WITH EMPTY KEY`

Comment: What version of SAP_ABA are you running on? The construction `FOR X = 1 THEN X + 1 WHILE X <= lw_max( X ) )` does not compile on my system (SAP_ABA 740 0009 SAPKA74009). Also, where is the method `lw_max` defined?

Comment: Doing as you wrote gives a syntax error `"LW_MAX( " expected, not "LW_MAX ("` ^^.

Comment: No, I meant `lw_max ( x )`. `lw_max` is a work field of type int. `( x )` is the  return of the `FOR` statement. I moved it to the next line to clarify this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113521/discussion-between-jagger-and-lpk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve will not be possible because the type of an inline definition of a variable using `COND` is decided at compilation time and not at runtime.

Please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994332/strange-behaviour-using-string-templates-and-new-cond-syntax). The type that will be taken is always the type of the variable that stands directly after `THEN`. You can decide what type will be chosen at compilation time by fiddling with negating the condition and switching places of variables after `THEN` at `ELSE` but it will be always either or and from what I understand you want to be able to do it dynamically so your `ASSIGN COMPONENT` statement works as expected with integers.

Even by specifically casting the variable after `ELSE` one gets the same short dump as you do.

```
DATA(li_temp) = COND #( WHEN i_field_customizing IS INITIAL
                        THEN VALUE t_integer_tt( ( 1 ) ( 2 ) )
                        ELSE CAST t_string_tt( REF #( i_field_customizing ) )->* ).
```

Alternatively you could cast to `REF TO DATA` but then you have to dereference it to a field symbol of type `STANDARD TABLE`.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    TYPES:
      t_integer_tt TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF i WITH EMPTY KEY,
      t_string_tt TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string WITH EMPTY KEY.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS:
      <fs_table> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
    DATA: BEGIN OF l_str,
      kunnr TYPE kunnr,
      name1 TYPE name1,
      END OF l_str.

*      DATA(i_field_customizing) = VALUE t_string_tt( ( `KUNNR` ) ( `NAME1` ) ).
      DATA(i_field_customizing) = VALUE t_string_tt( ).

      DATA(li_temp) = COND #( WHEN i_field_customizing IS INITIAL
                              THEN CAST data( NEW t_integer_tt( ( 1 ) ( 2 ) ) )
                              ELSE CAST data( REF #( i_field_customizing ) ) ).

      ASSIGN li_temp->* TO <fs_table>.

      LOOP AT <fs_table> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_temp>).
        ASSIGN COMPONENT <fs_temp> OF STRUCTURE l_str TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_field>).
      ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!